# Using article "the" for an artwork

Tags: articles

I want to name an artwork I made but I am not a native English speaker. The title I have selected is *vision*, meaning having insight. The point is I don't know whether I should name it *The Vision* or *Vision*.

Comment: It is your work; you can name it whatever you like. :) If it were mine, I would leave off the article. We talk about *the* Mona Lisa, but it is not *named* by Da Vinci at all, though it is probably a portrait of Lisa del Giocondo. Most works don't have "the' as part of the title.

Comment: "Vision" can suggest "eyesight" as well as "thing seen in a dream or trance." "The Vision" much more strongly suggests the latter alone.

Comment: How can this be anything other than primarily opinion-based?

Comment: @TimLymington, lack of proper English knowledge :)

Comment: @Susan, thanks for commenting on the post as a artist. That helps a lot.

Answer (score 2):

An article up front seems redundant: "Vision" looks good to me.

Comment: Thank you. I am happy that many people confirmed what I have already did.

Comment: @Naji: except that just as many people said you were wrong. Talk about perception bias.

Answer (score 1):

To answer this question, consider standard usage of the definite article. At http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/determiners-and-quantifiers/definite-article, there's a fairly comprehensive list of situations where the definite article is used. At least one is relevant here.

"We use the definite article in front of a noun when we believe the hearer/reader knows exactly what we are referring to. ... because there is only one"

There is only one Mona Lisa, and just about every reader know exactly what the name refers to.

You could justify calling your painting "The Vision," since that title would refer to the only vision you were portraying.

Comment: That is one of the few sources I actually looked but I couldn't relate it to any of the cases with a certainty! I've chosen the Vision but thank you.